# MongoDB facet subpipeline filter with equal values

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, facet

I have a collection with document structure

```
type: POSSIBLE VALUES ARE a1 or a2
emp_name: <<String>>
status: POSSIBLE VALUES ARE 0 or 1
```

I am using mongodb aggregate facet with 2 subpipeline

first subpipeline: filter type with a1, then group on emp_name, and project as empName and count

```
a1: [
    {
      $match: {
        type: "a1",
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          emp_name: "$emp_name",
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        empName : "$_id.emp_name",
        count: 1,
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
  ]
```

second subpipeline: filter type with a2 and project as emp_name, status and type

```
a2: [
    {
      $match: {
        type: "a2",
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        type: 1,
        emp_name: 1,
        status: 1,
        _id: 0,
      },
    }
  ]
```

facet will return 2 array of JSONObject, one have empName and count and other will have emp_name, status and type.

is it possible to get count, empName, status and type under a single object by validating equality on first subpipeline empName and second subpipeline emp_name

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jdTh2uRdehn  created an example playground. can you explain what the final should look like since it is not clear what should happen if a2 bucket have 2 elements with same name

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rf-TrTMTlfi

Comment: @cmgchess Could you please explain on aggregate query in mongoplayground.net/p/Rf-TrTMTlfi

Comment: sure after the faceting i'm doing a map over the a2 array and for each im finding the related object from a1 array and merging them. the next fields are basically getting the correct object format. somehing like this if done on js arrays https://codeshare.io/vAwgRn

Comment: Okay Thanks @cmgchess, but why we need to use $arrayElemAt and assigning to count var

Comment: because filter gives an array with 1 element if filter correctlt matched. the count should be that 1 element. it is like taking array[0]

Comment: @cmgchess could you please check once on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78025618/mongodb-facet-subpipeline-array-filter-with-condition