# MongoDB facet subpipeline array filter with condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, facet

I have aggregation with query as https://mongoplayground.net/p/jxaI7MAyBmJ

I have project type, count and empName by adding stages under data to filter with below 2 condition

1. type as a2 and
2. empName (type as a1) should need to equal with empName (type as a2).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "data": [
        {
          $match: {
            type: {
              $in: [
                "a1",
                "a2"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              emp_name: "$emp_name",
              type: "$type"
            },
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            empName: "$_id.emp_name",
            type: "$_id.type",
            count: 1,
            _id: 0
          }
        }
        
        //Have to ADD sub stages here with the above mentioned 2 condition
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

I tried on applying this condition however unable to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what you mean. What would be the desired output?

Comment: [{"data":[{"count":1,"empName":"John","type":"a2"},{"count":1,"empName":"Jane","type":"a2"},{"count":2,"empName":"Bob","type":"a2"}]}] this is the output

Comment: it has to show only type with a2 and empName should need to equal in both type a2 and a1

Comment: like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jsuqn1BugAy

Comment: Thanks @cmgchess mentioned condition have to add after the project in the facet, update the question and also https://mongoplayground.net/p/jxaI7MAyBmJ

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/jZ3SdHKSbpa  this? i copied the stages only small change done

Comment: diid above work?

Answer (score -1):

I still don't understand what you are looking for, but this one gives the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { type: { $in: ["a1", "a2"] } } },
   {
      $facet: {
         a1: [
            { $match: { type: "a1" } },
            { $project: { _id: 0, emp_name: 1 } }
         ],
         a2: [
            { $match: { type: "a2" } }
         ],
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$a2" },
   { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$a2.emp_name", "$a1.emp_name"] } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$a2.emp_name",
         count: { $count: {} },
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         _id: 0,
         type: "a2",
         count: 1,
         empName: "$_id"
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k8g16ePIUNk)

Comment: Thanks @Wernfried Here data Array has list of JSONObject with empName, type and count. we have to apply the mentioned condition after the project. Shared query is not applied with condition empName (type as a1) should need to equal with empName (type as a2) and also type as a2 has to apply after the project substage

Comment: Please see my update. Compared to proposal from @cmgchess is uses one `$group` less, thus it could be faster